# How to search by title or tags exclusively?

Tags: wp-query, search

I would like to modify the default search query of Wordpress to be able to get results from searching exclusively by tags or title. Meaning, it would show posts that contains a match from either the title or the tags. It would also completely ignore any match found inside the posts contents.

I have tried implementing it with this code:

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search;
    }

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}

add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

**Problem:** It only searches exclusively for title and does not include any resulting matches for tags. I tried to use the "Search Everything" plugin for searching by tags. The plugin works stand alone but completely gets ignored when used together with the code above.