# Admin Backend - Search Pages only by title

Tags: filters, search

I want to modify the pages search in the Admin Backend, so that the search only factor the title of the pages and not the whole text/article. I already found a code for `functions.php` that works perfectly for posts, but not for pages.

Here is the code for posts:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'admin_search_shops', null, 2 );

function admin_search_shops( $search, $a_wp_query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) return $search;

    $search = preg_replace( "# OR \(.*posts\.post_content LIKE \\'%.*%\\'\)#", "", $search );

    return $search;
}
```

I'm quite a noob in `PHP`, so I only know that I probably have to add some code to clarify that the `post_type` is `page`, but I don't know how and where.

Comment: Look into [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316122/how-to-search-by-title-or-tags-exclusively). Remember about `is_admin()` and `$a_wp_query->is_main_query()`.

Comment: okay, seems to work with this code. Thanks